# How to implement history of mysql events?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a MySQL table with next fields:

```
id int(11) primary auto_increment
data(text)
user varchar(20)
date text
```

I have a web based UI with php, where I show the data(data,user and date), and people can add or delete data as well. The results are seen into the table properly.

Now I want to implement a history somehow. So, if I deleted for instance a row one time, I want this to be seen in a lets say 'history' sql table. I want to store all the events(add or delete) by user and date ofcourse, that's all.

How should I approach this?

Comment: `date` should be of type `DATETIME`, and not `TEXT`. `data` should also be `VARCHAR(N)`.

Comment: depends on what data `data` actually stores...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually made my own "history" now. I created another table just for history entries and wrote another function (php) that performs every time that someone adds/deletes something and writes data into the pre-created table. Then I just show the data in a "History" page and it works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

This article should help you grasp an approach using triggers: http://codespatter.com/2008/05/06/how-to-use-triggers-to-track-changes-in-mysql/

Comment: This looks like just the thing I need. I'll look into it and see it I can establish that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy to answer with the information provided. In other words: Your question is very general.

I'll try to answer anyways: I think you should set up a table history, where the foreign key would be the user_id. Then you just save every action (add, delete, etc) in that table together with the user_id and a timestamp and say the data that was added or deleted or whatever other information could be useful. (*Update:* The way @Gibbs proposed is one possibility)

When you want to display the history you can easily select all actions taken by one user ordered by the timestamp.

One more thing: It is ***much*** better to use a datetime format for the date (e.g. timestamp) than using a VARCHAR.

Comment: I changed to datetime yeah :) created the history table as well, now need to figure out how to put the triggers up. need super privilege somehow..

Comment: I actually made my own "history" now. I created another table just for history entries and wrote another function (php) that performs every time that someone adds/deletes something and writes data into the pre-created table. Then I just show the data in a "History" page and it work well enough.

Comment: Good job :)    Just so you know why it is better to use a timestamp, take a look at the date and time functions of mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html With those functions it is very easy to select a certain period of time, say all actions from the history in the last month would be `SELECT * FROM history WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Answer (score 0):

I would have it so that all instances of the table are saved but you add a new column within your structure which shows 'live' rows.

For example:

```
------------------------------------------------
- id - user - data - live- date                -
------------------------------------------------
- 1  - 53   - ???  - 0   - 2012-07-16 15:51:45 -
- 1  - 53   - ???  - 0   - 2012-07-16 15:45:45 -
- 1  - 53   - ???  - 1   - 2012-07-16 14:51:42 -
- 1  - 53   - ???  - 0   - 2012-07-16 15:12:45 -
- 1  - 53   - ???  - 0   - 2012-07-16 13:54:21 -
- 1  - 53   - ???  - 0   - 2012-07-16 11:41:33 -
------------------------------------------------
```

I would then query the table to find the 'live' rows by adding in `WHERE live=1;`, that way, the rest is history.

Comment: and when would you put the row on "live" ? Can you explain how this would work on the site than? When someone added a new row, what happens? and when someone deletes a row, what than? How can i always show all the history events?

Comment: You can use the 'live' integer as anything you wanted. You could have it so that `0 = deleted, 1 = updated, 2 = latest`.. unlimited history events by using 'live' as an index.